# Why does distance vs period graph look linear for a pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, approximations

[image: Graph of the period vs length in cm]

**Question/problem**

In my introductory physics class in college, we were supposed to find a relationship between the length of a pendulum and the period.

Period=$2\pi*\sqrt{l/g}$

So thus i believed that I should be getting a square root relationship in the length vs the period but here it looks linear

I was wondering why is this?

And also i was asked another question- the period equation already has length in it and is it ok to describe a relationship with L on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually non linear. Try plotting more points and I think you'll get a square root graph. Also almost any graph zoomed in enough becomes a linear graph.

[image: graph]

This is a square root graph that looks linear when zoomed in enough.
[image: sqrt graph that looks linear]
This is the same graph that has more points plotted.
[image: sqrt graph]

Comment: Drawing the **best fit line** makes it linear.

Comment: @WrichikBasu I'm slightly implying dy/dx here but I think op understands.

Comment: @WrichikBasu, that's because a *line* IS linear.  That's why they call it a line and not a curve.  And note -  drawing a straight line through slightly curved data does not make the curved data straight.

Answer (score -1):

your y-axis does not start at 0, try changing the scale of the y-axis. This will show a square root relationship